# How to play online radio using .pls format in Android?

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android and I want to play online radio (example link http://www.bbc.co.uk/radio/listen/live/r1_aaclca.pls) using ParsePls. I have PlsParse code but after this I don't know how to play using the player in Android.

**PlsParser.java**

```
 public PlsParser(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
    this.reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file), 1024);
  }

  @Override
  public List<String> getUrls() {
    LinkedList<String> urls = new LinkedList<String>();
    while (true) {
      try {
        String line = reader.readLine();
        if (line == null) {
          break;
        }
        String url = parseLine(line);
        if (url != null && !url.equals("")) {
          urls.add(url);
        }
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
    return urls;
  }

  private String parseLine(String line) {
    if (line == null) {
      return null;
    }
    String trimmed = line.trim();
    if (trimmed.indexOf("http") >= 0) {
      return trimmed.substring(trimmed.indexOf("http"));
    }
    return "";
  }
}
```

and

> **PlaylistParser.java**

```
public interface PlaylistParser {
  public List<String> getUrls();
}
```

Basically I need to play online fm in Android. How can I do this?

Comment: Did you got the solution?Please post the solution if you got.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got some solution without Parse pls,
Just Enter URL of pls file in browser(example link [yp.shoutcast.com/sbin/tunein-station.pls?id=213352](http://yp.shoutcast.com/sbin/tunein-station.pls?id=213352)), 
you will get download "tunein-station.pls",
Just open the downloaded file with notepad,
you can see

```
[playlist]
numberofentries=2
File1=http://208.115.222.205:9938
Title1=(#1 - 1/100) RADIO CITY TAMIL
Length1=-1
File2=http://208.115.222.205:9948
Title2=(#2 - 67/300) RADIO CITY TAMIL
Length2=-1
Version=2
```

Here File1 URL(shoutcast online radio url)

Now using this URL i coded with mediaplayer.